# find array item in PHP

Tags: php

I have this array of items:

```
$tabslist = array('upload' => 'Upload File', 'pending_files' => 'Pending Files', 'call_data' => 'Call Data', 'services_data' => 'Services Data');
```

and i want to be able to find one of these items, i have tried using:

```
$title = array_search($_GET["tab"], $tabslist);
```

the value of `$_GET["tab"]` is `'upload'` so i want `$title` to be `'Upload File'`

Comment: what about `$title = isset($tabslist["$_GET['tab']"]) ? $tabslist["$_GET['tab']"] : "";` ??

Comment: if `$_GET['tab']` is `upload`, you don't need to search for the value. You already have the key. array_search will search through the values and return a key if the value is found. You already have the key. What you want to do is just check if the key is set and then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

```
$tabslist = array('upload' => 'Upload File', 'pending_files' => 'Pending Files', 'call_data' => 'Call Data', 'services_data' => 'Services Data');

$title = isset($tablist[$_GET["tab"]]) ? $tablist[$_GET["tab"]] : "";
```

**UPDATE**
as Hasse said in comment you can convert `$_GET["tab"]` to lowercase to insure correctness

```
$_GET['tab'] = strtolower( $_GET['tab'] );
$title = isset($tablist[$_GET["tab"]]) ? $tablist[$_GET["tab"]] : "";
```

Comment: We have arrived the same conclusion at the same time !! :)

Comment: You can also add a `$_GET['tab'] = strtolower( $_GET['tab'] );`